# How to set gravity top in collapsible toolbar layout

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

i am facing one issue in a collapsible toolbar after collapsing,toolbar is overlaping with tablayout.If i don't scroll it is working fine but if i scroll up they both are overlapping,i am dynamically changing toolbar collapse mode in fragments.[image]

code:

```
  private void setToolbarPin(Toolbar toolbar)
    {

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = toolbar.getLayoutParams();
        CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams newParams;
        if (params instanceof CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams) {
            newParams = (CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams)params;
        } else {
            newParams = new CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams(params);
        }

        newParams.setCollapseMode(CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams.COLLAPSE_MODE_OFF);
        newParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
        toolbar.setLayoutParams(newParams);






      //  toolbar.requestLayout();

    }
}
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            >


            <View
                android:id="@+id/customView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                ></View>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>



    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        >


    </FrameLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Why is your `Toolbar` below `TabLayout` and have `alignParentBottom` try to switch places of `Toolbar` and `Tablayout` and remove `alignParentBottom`

Comment: i am changing toolbar collapse mode status in one fragment in another fragment i am removing collapse mode

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:expanded="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="scrollable" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: For what are you using `View` inside your xml?

Comment: If you are trying to collapse `Toolbar` on scroll than you don't need `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and `View` at all. But if your `View` is for example `ImageView` and you are trying to collapse the `View` then you need `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

Comment: i need both view and tabs,in one fragment i want to show collapsing toolbar view in another fragment i need whatsapp type tabs,i am manipulating view height,i am setting toolbar collapse mode pin in first fragment and collapse mode off in second fragment
my problem is while it is in expanded mode then in next fragment it is working fine,but if i collapse in next fragment toolbar is overlapping with tablayout so what i thought i want to give some gravity top to toolbar layout but it is not working